# Codeigniter insert failed

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. I am trying to insert datat to mysql database to a table named `class_record`. My controller `add_record.php` coding as below :

```
class Add_record extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function index()
        {
            $this->load->model('add_record_model');
        }
    }
```

And my model `add_record_model` is as below :

```
class add_record_model extends CI_Model{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function index(){
        $data = array(

            'roll_number' => 15,
            'student_name' => 'Dhrubajyoti Baishya',
            'branch_code' => 'CS'
        );

        $this->db->insert('class_record',$data);
    }
    }
```

But when I type `http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/add_record` in url data are not inserted to the database. What is the problem ?

Comment: When you open the said URL, does the page open or no page appears at all? Maybe the problem is with URL

Comment: Are you sure your code is run? What if you put `die('foo bar');` in the model's `index` method and see if it's output?

Comment: OK..maybe the url problem ! I put `die('foo bar');` in the model's `index` and the page is blank !. what can be the problem? sorry I am only 3rd day to CI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually doing anything in the controller and models don't have index functions the way you're thinking.

You want something like this:

```
class Add_record extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('add_record_model');
        $this->add_record_model->insertRecords();
    }
}



class add_record_model extends CI_Model{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
function insertRecords(){
    $data = array(

        'roll_number' => 15,
        'student_name' => 'Dhrubajyoti Baishya',
        'branch_code' => 'CS'
    );

    $this->db->insert('class_record',$data);
}
}
```

The controller does what it says it controls things. By loading the model all you are doing is exposing the models functions to the controller to use directly. Honestly you would pass the data to the model from the controller as well, the function you have is a good little test function but does nada really. How you really want to be doing it is something along these lines.

```
class Add_record extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data = array(

        'roll_number' => 15,
        'student_name' => 'Dhrubajyoti Baishya',
        'branch_code' => 'CS'
    );
        $this->load->model('add_record_model');     
        $this->add_record_model->insertRecords($data);
    }
}



class add_record_model extends CI_Model{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
function insertRecords($data){       

    $this->db->insert('class_record',$data);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rick Calder. Special thanks for the explanation. Helped me a lot.